# Simultaneous jquery trigger

Tags: jquery

I am experiencing some problems combining multiple click handlers and running a process in an interval. During the Ajax requests I show an overlay and spinner and these disappear when done. Sometimes, when I click an element and at the same time the interval passes, the overlay is not disappearing.

Show/hide overlay and spinner

```
$(document).bind("ajaxStart", function() {
    $("#overlay").show();
    $('#wrapper').spin();
});

$(document).bind("ajaxStop", function () {
    $('#wrapper').spin(false);
    $("#overlay").hide();
});
```

Click event

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#dataTable tbody tr', function() {
    $.fn.enableMenuButtons();
}
... some other click events
```

Interval

```
setInterval( function () {
    $.fn.table.reload();
}, 10000);
```

I would like a interval to wait for any click events to complete if running. I've read something about deferred and promise, but I can't figure out how to apply this to my code.

Comment: How can you `click` an `element`. When the `spinner` is hiding everything.

Comment: I don't understand why you need `setInterval` after all.

Comment: You are right AjAX. I've updated the question. The problem occurs when I click an element and the interval passes before the click events complete. 

Ruzgar: I update a datatable on the background every 10 seconds. When there is no click event, I still want it to update.